# Zoom to fit user location and annotation map view swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, zooming, rect

My map view shows both the user location and annotation for the destination mural, but the zoom is off. How can I make it scale to fit the current location and the destination annotation based on how far apart they are and more centered?

This is how it zooms (so far away)
[image]

```
func mapPoints(){
    let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotations.title = muralModel.muralName!

    muralModel.getMainArtistModel(completion: { (anArtistModel) in
        annotations.subtitle  = " \(anArtistModel!.firstName!) \(anArtistModel!.lastName!)"
    })

    annotations.coordinate = coordinates

    muralLocation.addAnnotation(annotations)

    self.muralLocation.showsUserLocation = true

    var zoomRect: MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull
    let mapEdgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)

    //convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to MKMapPointForCoordinate so you don't end up in Bering Sea
    let userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(muralLocation.userLocation.coordinate)
    let destinationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinates)

    let userPointRect = MKMapRectMake(userPoint.x, userPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)
    let destinationPointRect = MKMapRectMake(destinationPoint.x, destinationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

    zoomRect = userPointRect
    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, destinationPointRect)

    muralLocation.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: mapEdgePadding, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'func setRegion(_ region: MKCoordinateRegion, animated: Bool)'. MKCoordinateRegion has a center and also defines a span for the region. The center here can be a point at an equal distance from the userLocation and the destination. You can decide the span accordingly.

Comment: let latSpan = muralLocation.userLocation.coordinate.latitude - coordinates.latitude
        let longSpan = muralLocation.userLocation.coordinate.longitude - coordinates.longitude
        
        
        var map = MKCoordinateRegion()
        
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latSpan, longSpan)
        
        map.center = muralLocation.userLocation.coordinate
        map.span = span

Comment: I did this, but the map zoom didn't budge... any help?